# Calendar program help (string variables)

Tags: python, string, function, variables, calendar

I recently signed up on this site because I am really stuck on the assignment in which I am required to create a program where the user inputs a month and the program displays how many days there are in that month. The user must also input the year so the program can check if it is a leap year in case the user inputs the month of february.

This is the coding I've come up with so far:

```
    def get_year():
    year = raw_input("Please enter the year: ")
    return year

def get_month():
    month = raw_input("Please enter the month: ")
    return month

def leap_year(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return true
    else:
        return false

def get_days(month):
    if month == "january":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "february" and leap_year == true:
        print "29 days"
    else:
        print "28 days"
    if month == "march":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "april":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "may":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "june":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "july":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "august":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "september":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "october":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "november":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "december":
        print "31 days"
    else:
        print

def main():
    user_year = get_year()
    user_month = get_month()
    leap_year(user_year)
    get_days(user_month)

main()
```

Anyways it's clear that there is an error in my get_days function its just I'm not sure
how to write the code so that the program knows that the user inputs a month such as
january or march. I'm guessing that the input has to be a variable and that since each 
month is a string, a variable string is needed. But I could be completely wrong about this.

I'm very new to python (exactly 2 weeks now of off and on programming for school work) so I'm not too sure on many of the specifics of python programming so if anybody could assist me in the proper direction, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using the python [calendar module](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html) from the python [standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html)?

Comment: You're quite close. A couple of hints: `get_days` needs to take two arguments, because you need the month _and_ the year (to test for leap year). Also, `leap_year` is a function, so you have to call it and pass it an argument. Also, your `if` statements are a little wonky. Look back over those to make certain they do what you expect. And finally, it should be `True` and `False`, not `true` and `false`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your algorithm to determine the leap year is quite accurate/complete. From Wikipeadia: "Years that are evenly divisible by 100 are not leap years, unless they are also evenly divisible by 400, in which case they are leap years" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Comment: You will also need to change the year from a string to a number before using calling leap_year function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were kinda close. I made some changes which I commented. And as Raymond Hettinger points out, your `get_days(month)` is **completely broken**.

```
def get_year():
    year = raw_input("Please enter the year: ")
    return int(year) #otherwise it is a string!

def get_month():
    month = raw_input("Please enter the month: ")
    return month

def leap_year(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_days(month,leap_year): #leap_year must be passes to this function
    #This checks for "january" and "february" with leap years
    #and falls back to last option on EVERYTHING ELSE like a feb without a leap year or even a "march"
    if month == "january":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "february" and leap_year == True:
        print "29 days"
    else:
        print "28 days"

    #this is a separate block that runs AFTER the previous block
    if month == "march":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "april":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "may":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "june":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "july":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "august":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "september":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "october":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "november":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "december":
        print "31 days"
    else:
        print "invalid input" #so that it doesnt fail silently when I enter 2

def main():
    user_year = get_year()
    user_month = get_month()
    leap_status = leap_year(user_year) #store the leap_year status to a variable
    get_days(user_month, leap_status)  #and then pass it to a function

main()
```

Comment: didn't even think about a leap_status variable or a leap_year passing. thanks a lot I got the program to work :)

Comment: Do remember to **accept** the answers which satisfy you by clicking the tick icon to the left of the answer. Rewards are what power this site. Dont make anybody remind you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The if-elif was being broken in February.  The minor change is to continue with an uninterrupted pattern of if-elif logic:

```
def get_days(month):
    if month == "january":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "february" and leap_year:
        print "29 days"
    elif month == "february" and not leap_year:
        print "28 days"
    elif month == "march":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "april":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "may":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "june":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "july":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "august":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "september":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "october":
        print "31 days"
    elif month == "november":
        print "30 days"
    elif month == "december":
        print "31 days"
    else:
        print 'unknown month'
```

Comment: now that I read your comment it makes so much more sense, I really can't believe I didn't think of it like that, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to using dictionary which a build-in data type in python.

```
def get_days(year, month):
    """
    take year and month ,return the days in that month.
    """
    #define a dictionary and the month is key which value is days 
    daydict = dict()    
    daydict = ['january'=31, 'february'=28, 'februaryinleapyear'=29,
                                        'march'=31, 'april'=30,
                                        'may'=31, 'june'=30,
                                        'july'=31, 'august'=31,
                                        'september'=30, 'october'=31,
                                        'november'=30, 'december'=31 ]

    try:
        if month in daydict:
            if month == 'february' and leap_year(year):     
                print daydict[februaryinleapyear] 
            else:
                print daydict[month]
        else:
            print 'The year or month you input is invalid !'
    except:
        print 'error!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 n=int(input('enter no of days in a month= '))
 #0=sunday
 #1=moday
 #2=tuesday
 #3=wednesday
 #4=thursday
 #5=friday
 #6=saturday
 d=int(input('enter the starting day of month= '))
 print('sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat',sep='\t')
 for j in range(d):
    print (' ',end='\t')
 i=1
 while(i<=n):
    print (i,end='\t')
    if(i+d)%7==0:
      print('\t')
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Some explanations about this code only answer would probably be useful.

Comment: its of printing the calendar by accepting no of days in a month and starting day of the month.it is useful for every year

Answer (score 0):

This code ask for user inputs( [more simple codes](https://code.dee-donald.com/2017/08/13/39/))

```
#python calendar days in month.
month= input ("Enter the month('January', ...,'December'): ")   # ask for inputs from user 

start=input ("Enter the start day ('Monday', ..., 'Sunday'): ")  


if start== "Monday" :
    num=1
elif start== "Tuesday" :
    num=0

elif start== "Wednesday" :
    num=-1

elif start== "Thursday" :
    num=-2   

elif start== "Friday" :
    num=-3 

elif start== "Sartday" :
    num=-4
elif start=="Sunday":
    num=-5


print(month)    
print("Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su")  #the header of the Calender


if month== "January" or month=="March" or month=="May" or month=="July" or month=="August" or month=="October" or month=="December" :

  #for month with 31 days
    for num_ in range (num,num+41,7): 
        for i in range(7):
            if num<1:
                print ('   ',end="")
            elif num>31:
                print("",end="")
            else:
                print ("{0:>2}".format(num),end="")
                if i<6 and num<31:
                    print(" ",end="") 
            num +=1
        print() 


elif month== "April" or month=="June" or month=="Septemmber" or month=="November":
   #for month with 30 days      
    for num_ in range (num,num+41,7): 
        for i in range(7):
            if num<1:
                print ('   ',end="")
            elif num>30:
                print("",end="")
            else:
                print ("{0:>2}".format(num),end="")
                if i<6 and num<30:
                    print(" ",end="") 
            num +=1
        print() 


elif month== "February" :
  # february is an exception : it has 28 days 
    for num_ in range (num,num+41,7): 
        for i in range(7):
            if num<1:
                print ('   ',end="")
            elif num>28:
                print("",end="")
            else:

                print ("{0:>2}".format(num),end="")
                if i<6 and num<28:
                    print(" ",end="") 
            num +=1
        print() 


else:
    print("invalid entry")
```